# OData and $expand for one record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

In ASP.NET WebApi project is method like:

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetById(int id)
        {
            var entity = repository.GetById(id);

            if (entity == null)
            {                
                var message = string.Format("No {0} with ID = {1}", GenericTypeName, id);
                return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
        }
```

I'm using OData to get values of navigation properties. When I'm using `$expand` with GET `http://localhost:3761/api/House?$expand=Address` then everything works fine. I need to use `$expand` in my `GetById(id)` method for one record like:

```
 http://localhost:3761/api/House/1?$expand=Address
```

Please suggest me what is the easiest way to implement it?

I found some information here and on other sites but it did not help me.

Comment: Are you using WebApi 2? did you tried this? : http://localhost/api/House(1)?$expand=Address

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value

Comment: @kamus I need to use `http://localhost:3761/api/House/1?$expand=Address` not `House(1)`. This is the main reason for which I wrote here